# identity server 4 and Ocelot integration With Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, identityserver4, ocelot

I am trying to integrate Ocelot API gateway with ID4. As per Ocelot [documentation](http://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/authentication.html#identity-server-bearer-tokens)  we can validate token with external id server *https://whereyouridentityserverlives.com*, Now,  i'm integrating ID server and GateWay in same docker compose,

```
gateway:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: GateWay/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - identityserver
    links: 
      - identityserver
    networks:
      - api_backend
  identityserver: 
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}identityserver:dev
    networks:
      - api_backend

networks:
  api_backend:
    driver: "bridge"
```

and in my gateway, I am configuring like

```
ConfigureServices(s => {
                    s.AddAuthentication()
                        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("TestKey", o =>
                        {
                            o.Authority = "https://identityserver";
                            o.ApiName = "api1";
                            o.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Both; 
                        });
```

Everything works upto this, Now at the time of token validation it is getting error, **No such device or address**

Most likely, gateway server is not able to connect id4, and hence not able to get the discovery document.

#### Relevant parts of the log file

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44326/b
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44326/b
Ocelot.Errors.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware:Debug: requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: ocelot pipeline started
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Ocelot.Errors.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: ocelot pipeline started
Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware:Debug: requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Upstream url path is /b
Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware:Debug: requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: downstream templates are /api/values
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0]
requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Upstream url path is /b
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0]
requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: downstream templates are /api/values
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Ocelot.RateLimit.Middleware.ClientRateLimitMiddleware[0]
requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: EndpointRateLimiting is not enabled for /api/values
Ocelot.RateLimit.Middleware.ClientRateLimitMiddleware:Information: requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: EndpointRateLimiting is not enabled for /api/values
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Ocelot.Authentication.Middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware[0]
requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: /b is an authenticated route. AuthenticationMiddleware checking if client is authenticated
Ocelot.Authentication.Middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware:Information: requestId: 0HLF9AEP1C9GQ:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: /b is an authenticated route. AuthenticationMiddleware checking if client is authenticated
The thread 422 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 435 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
Exception occurred while processing message.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such device or address ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such device or address
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Error: Exception occurred while processing message.

System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such device or address ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such device or address
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem with ocelot + docker + Id4 + other services

Comment: Are you developing on Windows? I might have the answer because something similar occurred to me.

Comment: @michajas yes, i'm able to solve the issue. actually the issue was related to certificate, and it is not related to id4 and ocelot

Comment: @emmanuel hey, I was able to solve the issue, Thanks for checking.